# Probability of interview results

Tags: probability

My question says,

**Sixty people were interviewed about their music preferences.  The results showed that 45 people liked country, 20 liked classic rock, and 15 liked country and classic rock.  If a person is selected randomly from the group, what is the probability that the person:**

**a) likes both country and classic rock**

**b) likes country or classic rock**

**c) does not like country or classic rock**

**d) likes only one type of either music**

I've learned of permutations before and have learned to solve similar questions. I'm just not sure how to solve the question now that probability is a factor in the question. Im very confused and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just count each desired case and divide by the total number of people.  For instance, for the first part, we know there are exactly $15$ people who like both, so the desired probability in this case is $\frac {15}{60}=\frac 14$.

Comment: When I was learning how to solve these type of questions I realized that often probability just means the amount of things you're interested in divided by the total amount of things.

Comment: @jwc845 that is true if selection from the set of available things is done uniformly at random (*which it presumably is here*).  It is important to remember that that is no longer true when we don't know.  Although there are two outcomes to the lottery, you either win or you lose, the probability of winning is not simply $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I completely agree. I just find many textbook combinatorics-style problems presume the selection is done uniformly at random unless otherwise stated.

Answer (score 0):

If 45 people liked country, and 15 liked both country and rock, then 45-15=30 people like country but not rock. Likewise, 20-15=5 people like rock and not country. Notice that these three categories add up to 30+5+15=50. But we're told 60 people were polled. So that means 10 of the people didn't like *either* genre of music.

To find each probability, add up the number of people who match that description exactly, and put that over the total number, 60.

- A) This is just 15/60, which reduces to 1/4.
- B) This includes three groups of people: the ones who like both, the ones who like country but not rock, and the ones who like rock but not country. So add up those three numbers and divide by 60.

Use a similar strategy to answer the other two questions.